# Dilation on 3D Images?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, convolution

I need to apply a dilated convolution to a 3D image, but dilation values greater than 1 are not currently supported in v11.3:

```
conv = NetInitialize@
  ConvolutionLayer[3, 3, "Dilation" -> 2, "PaddingSize" -> 1, 
   "Input" -> NetEncoder[{"Image3D", {5, 5, 5}}], 
   "Output" -> NetDecoder["Image3D"]]
```

[image]

Is there some undocumented way, perhaps with MXNetLink, to hack around this issue?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, MXNet does not support 3D convolutions with dilations yet. This can be seen in the [MXNet source for convolution](https://github.com/apache/incubator-mxnet/blob/05f9429ff721f61d030c17b4585cc94643787241/src/operator/nn/convolution.cc#L213).

Comment: Then would it be possible to write it in top level code?

Comment: No, the custom layer functionality is not in 11.3. But even if you could implement it in top-level, it will be unlikely to be fast enough for NN training...

Comment: Is there a good chance that custom layers will be coming in 11.4?

Comment: It will depend on the new compiler being ready (also, there probably won't be a 11.4, just 12), as we will only allow compiled functions as custom layers. If the compiler is ready, then there is a very good chance this will be available.

Comment: Hi, Sebastian, I think there are many bugs about the Transfer of MXNet model both Mathematica or MXNet, such like MXNet cannot load Mathematica model with aux_states like a LSTM model, Do you know when will Mathematica 12 be published? and When will such problem be solved?